# Hadoop: How can I start tasktracker?

Tags: hadoop

***I want to open web/ui of tasktracker***. *localhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp*
But it doesn't work since there's no running tasktracker. My hadoop applications have been working well without tasktracker. But I found that tasktracker should be running in order to open web/ui. But I don't know how to start tasktracker. ***How can I start tasktracker?*** I tried lots of things but they don't work.

My status & environment: *localhost:50070* web/ui is working well. jps command shows Datanode, NameNode, NodeManager, SecondaryNameNode, ResourceManager. Hadoop version is 2.2.0. Os is Red Hat 6.3(Santiago).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Hadoop 2.2.0 which has YARN framework, there is no `jobtracker` in it. Its functionality is split and replaced by `ResourceManager` and `ApplicationMaster`. Here is expected `jps` prinout while running YARN

```
$jps
18509 Jps
17107 NameNode
17170 DataNode
17252 ResourceManager
17309 NodeManager
17626 JobHistoryServer
```

Answer (score 1):

From the master node, you can start the jobtracker and the tasktrackers of the slaves (these are the nodes in the file `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/slaves`) with the command:

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-mapred.sh`

If you want to start a tasktracker separately, from this node type:

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop-daemons.sh start tasktracker`

Replace `start` with `stop` in the commands above for stopping the jobtracker and tasktrackers, respectively.

By the way, I think that you need to start the jobtracker, in order to see what you want, even if no tasktracker is running.

**EDIT**: These commands were used in the old API. The new API uses the following commands:

```
$ cd $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME
$ sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
$ sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
```

, as described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).